# Simplifying Derivation Expression Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am using Scheme language to take the derivative of an inputted expression, and for the most part I believe my table driven function is working well enough but now I'd like to create a few expressions to handle simplifying the output. 
For Example: 
(d '(* (+ x 1) (+ x -1))) -> '(* 2 x) Rather than -> '(+ (* (+ x 1) (+ 1 0)) (* (+ 1 0) (+ x -1)))

I am rather new to Scheme so I know this is just a matter of being able to recursively parse lists but I'm not sure where to start, any idea how to achieve this?

Here is my code for the function

```
(define lookup (lambda (x alist) (cadr (assoc x alist))))


;-----------------------------------------------------

(define d
  (lambda (e)
    (cond ((number? e) 0)
      ((equal? e 'x) 1)
      (else
       (let ((op (car e)) (args (cdr e)))
         (apply (lookup op d-op-table) args))))))


(define d-op-table
  (list(list '+   (lambda (u v)(list '+ (d u) (d v))))
       (list '-   (lambda (u v)(list '- (d u) (d v))))
       (list '*   (lambda (u v)(list '+ (list '* u (d v))(list '* (d u) v))))
       (list 'sin (lambda (u)(list '*( list 'cos (d u)))))
       (list 'cos (lambda (u)(list '*( list '-sin (d u)))))
       (list 'log (lambda (u)(list '* (list '/ 1 u) (d u))))
       (list 'exp (lambda (u)(list '* (d u)(list 'exp u))))
       (list 'expt (lambda (u v) (list 'expt (list '* v  u) (- v 1))))))
```

Comment: Simplifying expressions is completely independent of and unrelated to calculating derivatives.

Comment: It's basically a pattern matching and replacement process, e.g. `(+ anything 0)` simplifies to `anything`.

Comment: I am wanting to simplify the output of the derivative
As put above instead of getting '(+ (* (+ x 1) (+ 1 0)) (* (+ 1 0) (+ x -1)))  from taking the derivative of (* (+ x 1) (+ x -1)))  I am trying to have it simplify to (* 2 x)
Being new to Scheme I'm unsure how to parse through the list easily to simplify it, given general simplification can be a rather difficult task

Comment: I understand what you want. Like I said, it's a totally separate operation. `(define simplify ...)` and then you do `(simplify (d '(...))`

Comment: You could also call it automatically from `d`: `(simplify (apply (lookup op d-op-table) args))`